# Jmeter: Parameter settings

Tags: csv, jmeter

Is it possible for each thread select the same row from the CSV file?

eg. I have 5 users and only 5 records (rows) in my CSV file. In each iteration, the 1st value from CSV should be assigned to User1, similarly for all users.

```
User1: myID1,pass1,item1,product1
User2: myID2,pass2,item2,product2
User3: myID3,pass3,item3,product3
User4: myID14,pass4,item4,product4
User5: myID15,pass5,item5,product5
```

.
.
Any solution, please?

Comment: How many threads will you have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you have only 5 threads and 5 lines in CSV I would suggest considering switching to [User Parameters](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters) instead of working with CSV.
2. If your CSV file can have > 5 lines and your test can have > 5 virtual users and requirement like "user 1 takes line 1" is a must, you will have to pre-load the CSV file into memory with a scripting test element like [Beanshell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) like:

   - Add setUp Thread Group to your Test Plan (with 1 thread and 1 iteration)
   - Add Beanshell Sampler and put the following code into "Script" area:

     ```
     import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

     List lines = FileUtils.readLines(new File("test.csv"));
     bsh.shared.lines = lines;
     ```

   The above code will read the contents of `test.csv` file (replace it with relative or full path to your CSV file) and store it into [bsh.shared namespace](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_variables)

   - Add Beanshell PreProcessor as a child of the request where you need to use the values from the CSV file and put the following code into "Script" area:

     ```
     int user = ctx.getThreadNum();
     String line = bsh.shared.lines.get(user);

     String[] tokens = line.split(",");

     vars.put("ID", tokens[0]);
     vars.put("pass", tokens[1]);
     vars.put("item", tokens[2]);
     vars.put("product", tokens[3]);
     ```

   The above code will fetch the line from the list, stored in the `bsh.shared` namespace basing on current virtual user number, split it by comma and store the values into the JMeter Variables so you will be able to access them as:

   - `${ID}`
   - `${pass}`
   - `${item}`
   - `${product}`

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on using Beanshell scripting in JMeter tests.